# Standard Algebraic Derivative Calculator

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp, math-expression-eval

I had some difficulty with this problem, so I'm sure there is a better way.  Here is the question from [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html):

> **Exercise 2.58**
>
> Suppose we want to
>   modify the differentiation program so
>   that it works with ordinary
>   mathematical notation, in which + and
>   * are infix rather than prefix operators. Since the differentiation
>   program is defined in terms of
>   abstract data, we can modify it to
>   work with different representations of
>   expressions solely by changing the
>   predicates, selectors, and
>   constructors that define the
>   representation of the algebraic
>   expressions on which the
>   differentiator is to operate.
>
> **a.** Show how to do this in order to
>   differentiate algebraic expressions
>   presented in infix form, such as
>
> ```
> (x + (3 * (x + (y + 2))))
> ```
>
> To simplify the task, assume that +
>   and * always take two arguments and
>   that expressions are fully parenthesized.
>
> **b.** The problem becomes substantially
>   harder if we allow standard algebraic
>   notation, such as
>
> ```
> (x + 3 * (x + y + 2))
> ```
>
> which drops unnecessary
>   parentheses and assumes that
>   multiplication is done before
>   addition. Can you design appropriate
>   predicates, selectors, and
>   constructors for this notation such
>   that our derivative program still
>   works?

I wrote the following solution to part b (some parts came from the text):

```
(define (deriv exp var)
  (cond ((number? exp) 0)
        ((variable? exp)
         (if (same-variable? exp var) 1 0))
        ((sum? exp)
         (make-sum (deriv (addend exp) var)
                   (deriv (augend exp) var)))
        ((product? exp)
         (make-sum
          (make-product (multiplier exp)
                        (deriv (multiplicand exp) var))
          (make-product (deriv (multiplier exp) var)
                        (multiplicand exp))))
        (else
         (error "unknown expression type -- DERIV" exp))))

(define (variable? x) (symbol? x))

(define (same-variable? v1 v2)
  (and (variable? v1) (variable? v2) (eq? v1 v2)))

(define (join op seq)
  (foldr (lambda (a b) (cons a (if (null? b) b (cons op b)))) null seq))

(define (make-sum . a)
  (define (iter sum rest) 
    (cond ((null? rest) (if (zero? sum) '() (list sum)))
          ((=number? (car rest) 0) (iter sum (cdr rest)))
          ((number? (car rest)) (iter (+ sum (car rest)) (cdr rest)))
          (else (cons (car rest) (iter sum (cdr rest))))))
  (let ((result (iter 0 a)))
    (cond ((null? result) 0)
          ((= (length result) 1) (car result))
          (else (join '+ result)))))

(define (=number? exp num)
  (and (number? exp) (= exp num)))

(define (make-product . a)
  (define (iter product rest)
    (cond ((null? rest) (if (= 1 product) '() (list product)))
          ((=number? (car rest) 1) (iter product 
                                         (cdr rest)))
          ((number? (car rest)) (iter (* product (car rest)) 
                                      (cdr rest)))
          (else 
           (let ((result (iter product (cdr rest))))
             (if (and (pair? result) (eq? (car result) 0))
                 (list 0)
                 (cons (car rest) result))))))
  (let ((result (iter 1 a)))
    (cond ((null? result) 1)
          ((eq? (length result) 1) (car result))
          (else (join '* result)))))

(define (sum? x)
  (and (pair? x) 
       (or 
        (member '+ x)
        (and (eq? 1 (length x)) 
             (pair? (car x)) 
             (pair? (member '+ (car x)))))))

(define (items-before op seq)
  (if (eq? (cadr seq) op)
      (list (car seq))
      (cons (car seq) (items-before op (cdr seq)))))

(define (items-after op seq)
  (if (eq? (car seq) op) 
      (cdr seq)
      (items-after op (cdr seq))))

(define (addend s) (if (and (eq? (length s) 1) (pair? (car s)))
                       (addend (car s))
                       (let ((result (items-before '+ s)))
                         (if (eq? 1 (length result)) (car result) result))))

(define (augend s) (if (and (eq? (length s) 1) (pair? (car s)))
                       (augend (car s))
                       (let ((result (items-after '+ s)))
                         (if (eq? 1 (length result)) (car result) result))))

(define (product? x)
  (define (no-plus-just-times seq) (not (member '+ seq)) (pair? (member '* seq)))
  (and (pair? x) 
       (or 
        (and (no-plus-just-times x))
        (and (eq? (length x) 1) (pair? (car x)) (no-plus-just-times (car x))))))

(define (multiplier p) (if (and (eq? (length p) 1) (pair? (car p)))
                           (multiplier (car p))
                           (car p)))

(define (multiplicand p) (if (eq? (length p) 1) 
                             (if (pair? (car p)) 
                                 (multiplicand (car p)) 
                                 (car p)) 
                             (caddr p)))
```

How can this be improved?